# Unable to run Kops Template

Tags: kubernetes, kops

I'm currently trying to build out a Kops template using the Kops toolbox cli. Unfortunately when I run the command I get the following error:

```
unable decode the configuration file: /dev/fd/63, error: error converting YAML to JSON: yaml: control characters are not allowed
```

I'm quite new to Kops and go templating in general so I was wondering if anyone has run into this issue before? Here is my cluster-template.yaml:

```
apiVersion: kops.k8s.io/v1alpha2
kind: Cluster
metadata:
  name: {{ .clusterName.value }}
spec:
  additionalPolicies:
    node: |
      [
        {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Action": [
            "sts:AssumeRole"
          ],
          "Resource": [
            "arn:aws:iam:::role/k8s-*"
          ]
        }
      ]
  api:
    loadBalancer:
      crossZoneLoadBalancing: true
      type: Internal
      class: Network
  authentication:
    aws: {}
  authorization:
    rbac: {}
  channel: stable
  cloudProvider: aws
  clusterAutoscaler:
    enabled: true
    cpuRequest: "100m"
    memoryRequest: "300Mi"
  configBase: {{ .state.value }}/{{ .clusterName.value }}
  containerRuntime: docker
  dnsZone: {{ .dnsZone.value }}.k8s
  etcdClusters:
  - cpuRequest: 200m
    etcdMembers:
  {{ range $i, $az := .availability_zones.value }}
    - instanceGroup: master-{{ . }}
      name: {{  . | replace $.region.value "" }} {{ /* converts us-east-1a to a */ }}
  {{ end }}
    memoryRequest: 100Mi
    name: main
  - cpuRequest: 100m
    etcdMembers:
  {{ range $i, $az := .availability_zones.value }}
    - instanceGroup: master-{{ . }}
      name: {{ . | replace $.region.value "" }} {{ /* converts us-east-1a to a */ }}
  {{ end }}
    memoryRequest: 100Mi
    name: events
  iam:
    allowContainerRegistry: true
    legacy: false
  kubeDNS:
    provider: CoreDNS
    nodeLocalDNS:
      enabled: true
      memoryRequest: 5Mi
      cpuRequest: 25m
  kubelet:
    anonymousAuth: false
    authenticationTokenWebhook: true
    authorizationMode: Webhook
  kubernetesApiAccess:
  - 192.168.0.0/24
  - 192.168.4.0/24
  - 192.168.5.0/24
  - 192.168.10.0/24
  kubernetesVersion: 1.19.7
  kubeProxy:
    proxyMode: ipvs
    ipvsScheduler: lc
  masterInternalName: internal.{{ .clusterName.value }}
  masterPublicName: {{ .clusterName.value }}
  networkCIDR: {{ .vpc_cidr.value }}
  networkID: {{ .vpc_id.value }}
  networking:
    weave:
      mtu: 8912
  nonMasqueradeCIDR: 100.64.0.0/10
  sshAccess:
  - 192.168.0.0/24
  - 192.168.4.0/24
  - 192.168.5.0/24
  - 192.168.10.0/24
  subnets:
  # Private Subnets, one per AZ
  {{ range $i, $id := .private_subnet_ids.value }}
  - cidr: {{ index $.private_subnet_ids.value $i }}
    egress: {{  index $.nat_gateway_ids.value $i }}
    id: {{ . }}
    name: {{ index $.availability_zones.value $i }}
    type: Private
    zone: {{ index $.availability_zones.value $i }}
  {{ end }}
  topology:
    dns:
      type: Private
    masters: private
    nodes: private

---

# Creating one master per AZ
{{ range $.availability_zones.value }}
apiVersion: kops.k8s.io/v1alpha2
kind: InstanceGroup
metadata:
  labels:
    kops.k8s.io/cluster: {{ .clusterName.value }}
  name: master-{{ . }}
spec:
  image: 099720109477/ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-focal-20.04-amd64-server-20210119.1
  machineType: m5.large
  maxSize: 1
  minSize: 1
  nodeLabels:
    kops.k8s.io/instancegroup: master-{{ . }}
  role: Master
  subnets:
  - {{ . }}

---
  {{ end }}

{{ range .availability_zones }}
apiVersion: kops.k8s.io/v1alpha2
kind: InstanceGroup
metadata:
  labels:
    kops.k8s.io/cluster: {{ .clusterName }}
  name: nodes-{{ . }}
spec:
  image: 099720109477/ubuntu/images/hvm-ssd/ubuntu-focal-20.04-amd64-server-20210119.1
  machineType: m5.xlarge
  maxSize: 5
  minSize: 3
  nodeLabels:
    kops.k8s.io/instancegroup: nodes-{{ . }}
  role: Node
  subnets:
  - {{ . }}

---
  {{ end }}
```

My end goal is to take this template and combine it with some inputs to dynamically build templates based on our environment.

Comment: The template in itself looks good. Maybe there are some non-breaking white space that has snuck in or something? If you have an example values file, I can try to reproduce.

Comment: Thanks for validating!

Answer (score 0):

This was related to my values file, not my cluster template.